# Nested For Loops, inside loop not reacting

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to insert columns with the appropriate month and year heading. The loop functions correctly, my inside for loop that attaches the year isn't functioning properly. I understand why, it's because there is no full loop on the outside for statement. I've been trying to find a way to insert checks to no avail, and nor can I find a way that does it outside of the loop properly.

Brief explaination of what it should look like:
It's seperated into quarters currently, so I'm trying to insert months before each quarter, with the year attached. It looks like this, I just can't get the years to associate to the correct columns. For some reason it skips straight to 20 as opposed to filling correctly

```
      Col1   Col2  Col3  Col4 Col5  Col6 ....Colx
Row 1 01/13  02/13 03/13 Q1   04/13 05/13....01/14  
Row 2  

Sub Months()
'Inserts month headings for vlookup quantity information
Dim y As String
y = "Q1"
If y = "" Then Exit Sub
Dim x As Long
For x = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Column To 1 Step -1
If Cells(1, x).value = y Then
Columns(x).EntireColumn.Insert
Columns(x).EntireColumn.Insert
Columns(x).EntireColumn.Insert
For i = 13 To 20
Cells(1, x).value = "01/01/" & i
Cells(1, x).NumberFormat = "mm-yy"
Cells(1, x + 1).value = "02/01/" & i
Cells(1, x + 1).NumberFormat = "mm-yy"
Cells(1, x + 2).value = "03/01/" & i
Cells(1, x + 2).NumberFormat = "mm-yy"
Next i
End If
Next x

Dim y2 As String
y2 = "Q2"
If y = "" Then Exit Sub
Dim x2 As Long
For x2 = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Column To 1 Step -1
If Cells(1, x2).value = y2 Then
Columns(x2).EntireColumn.Insert
Columns(x2).EntireColumn.Insert
Columns(x2).EntireColumn.Insert
For i2 = 13 To 20
Cells(1, x2).value = "04/01/" & i2
Cells(1, x2).NumberFormat = "mm-yy"
Cells(1, x2 + 1).value = "05/01/" & i2
Cells(1, x2 + 1).NumberFormat = "mm-yy"
Cells(1, x2 + 2).value = "06/01/" & i2
Cells(1, x2 + 2).NumberFormat = "mm-yy"
Next i2
End If
Next x2
```

I'm also including my attempt to do it outside of the for loop, it's just going to have to repeat so I can get each month.

```
Sub replace()

'Adds year
Dim Name As String
Name = "1/1/"
LR = Range("1:1" & Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlLeft).Column)
For Each c In LR
For i = 13 To 20
If Cells(1, c.Column) = Name Then
Cells(1, c.Column) = Name & i
End If
Next i
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I just looked at your code for a second, but what I'm seeing is stuff like, on your inside for loop (looping through `i`), the following `For i = 13 To 20 Cells(1, x).value = "01/01/" & i` - This would repeat the same calculation on the same cell... I think what you wanted to have was `Cells(i, x).value = "01/01/" & i` ... That now loops through your `i` variable on the cells... Again, just a quick glance....

Comment: I just want i to be the year value, the 1 is there so it stays in the first row. if it gets inputed as 01/01/13 it automatically formats it as a date, which is what I want. thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand what you are trying to achieve but the code you currently have will always produce values such as `01/01/20, 02/01/20, ...`. Your inner loop (`For i = 13 To 20`) loops always replacing `i` until it hits 20 (as `x` isn't being incremented).

I suspect you want to re-arrange your loops to maybe something like this:

```
For i = 13 To 20
    For x = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Column To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(1, x).value = y Then
            Columns(x).EntireColumn.Insert
            Columns(x).EntireColumn.Insert
            Columns(x).EntireColumn.Insert

            Cells(1, x).value = "01/01/" & i
            Cells(1, x).NumberFormat = "mm-yy"
            Cells(1, x + 1).value = "02/01/" & i
            Cells(1, x + 1).NumberFormat = "mm-yy"
            Cells(1, x + 2).value = "03/01/" & i
            Cells(1, x + 2).NumberFormat = "mm-yy"
        End If
    Next x
Next i
```

An alternative could be something like this:

```
const intSTART_YEAR As Integer = 13
const intEND_YEAR As Integer = 20

i = intSTART_YEAR
For x = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Column To 1 Step -1
    If Cells(1, x).value = y Then
        Columns(x).EntireColumn.Insert
        Columns(x).EntireColumn.Insert
        Columns(x).EntireColumn.Insert


        Cells(1, x).value = "01/01/" & i
        Cells(1, x).NumberFormat = "mm-yy"
        Cells(1, x + 1).value = "02/01/" & i
        Cells(1, x + 1).NumberFormat = "mm-yy"
        Cells(1, x + 2).value = "03/01/" & i
        Cells(1, x + 2).NumberFormat = "mm-yy"
        i = i + 1
        if i > intEND_YEAR then
            exit for
        end if
    End If
Next x
```