# Excel 2013 proper syntax for dynamic data range in VBA loop

Tags: excel, syntax, excel-2013, vba

Nanashi's reply helped me to modify the code below; the chart now responds properly.  Would like to adjust further such that strfieldrange will offset one column farther to the right each time the loop steps to the next series (e.g., $Z$4:$Z$159 should become $AA$4:$AA$159 in the second step of the loop).  I'm learning so please excuse the rough edges.

```
Sub stacklabels2()

finalrow = Worksheets("Stacking RR").Range("Z" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'trying to derive the proper range dynamically
' sensing that I need another variable here that will allow me to cause strfieldrange to step with the loop
strfieldrange = "=" & "'Stacking RR'!" & Range("$Z$4:$Z$159").Address

Sheets("Stacking").Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("StackingPlan").Activate

ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelNone)
ActiveChart.ApplyDataLabels

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("StackingPlan").Activate
For Each Ser In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
    Ser.DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.InsertChartField msoChartFieldRange, strfieldrange, 0
    Ser.DataLabels.ShowRange = True
    Ser.DataLabels.ShowValue = False
Next Ser
End Sub
```

Any ideas?  Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I think I solved it.  Substituting the following code into the larger macro from above works:

```
keycolumn = Range("Z4").Column

For Each Ser In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
    n = Val(Ser.Name)
    Ser.DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.InsertChartField msoChartFieldRange, CStr("='Stacking RR'!" & Range(Cells(4, keycolumn + n), Cells(LastRow, keycolumn + n)).Address), 0
    Ser.DataLabels.ShowRange = True
    Ser.DataLabels.ShowValue = False
Next Ser
```

Awesome.  Thanks to [@nanashi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2548721/nanashi) for all of his help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working code:

```
Sub StackLabels()

Dim WS0 As Worksheet, WS1 As Worksheet
Dim RngHeader As Range, RngCell As Range
Dim StrField As String
Dim LastRow As Long, ResizeRow As Long

With ThisWorkbook
    Set WS0 = .Sheets("Stacking RR")
    Set WS1 = .Sheets("Stacking")
End With

With WS0
    LastRow = .Range("Z" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ResizeRow = LastRow - 3 'If data begins at row 4, subtract 1 to get correct starting row of data.
    Set RngHeader = .Range("Z4:AS4")
End With

WS1.ChartObjects("StackingPlan").Activate

ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelNone)
ActiveChart.ApplyDataLabels
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("StackingPlan").Activate

keycolumn = Range("Z4").Column

For Each Ser In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
    n = Val(Ser.Name)
    Ser.DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.InsertChartField msoChartFieldRange, CStr("='Stacking RR'!" & Range(Cells(4, keycolumn + n), Cells(LastRow, keycolumn + n)).Address), 0
    Ser.DataLabels.ShowRange = True
    Ser.DataLabels.ShowValue = False
Next Ser

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

It takes a raw formula string, as evidenced by the "=" in the beginning. Try doing it like this:

```
Sub Blah()

' Other code.
StrFieldRange = "=" & Range("A1").Resize(10, 1).Address
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart1").Activate

For Each Ser In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
    Ser.DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.InsertChartField _
    msoChartFieldRange, StrFieldRange, 0
Next
'Etc.

End Sub
```

This should be equivalent to using: `=$A$1:$A$10`. Let us know if this helps.

**EDIT:**

As per discussion:

```
Sub StackLabelsMod()

    Dim WS0 As Worksheet, WS1 As Worksheet
    Dim RngHeader As Range, RngCell As Range
    Dim StrField As String
    Dim LastRow As Long, ResizeRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set WS0 = .Sheets("Stacking RR")
        Set WS1 = .Sheets("Stacking")
    End With

    With WS0
        LastRow = .Range("Z" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ResizeRow = LastRow - 3 'If data begins at row 4, subtract 1 to get correct starting row of data.
        Set RngHeader = .Range("Z4:AS4")
    End With

    For Each RngCell In RngHeader

        StrField = "='Stacking RR'!" & RngCell.Resize(ResizeRow, 1).Address
        WS1.ChartObjects("StackingPlan").Activate

        ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementDataLabelNone)
        ActiveChart.ApplyDataLabels
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("StackingPlan").Activate

        For Each Ser In ActiveChart.SeriesCollection
            Ser.DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.InsertChartField msoChartFieldRange, StrField, 0
            Ser.DataLabels.ShowRange = True
            Ser.DataLabels.ShowValue = False
        Next Ser

    Next

End Sub
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yes, this works.  Thank you very much.  I'd like to have the raw formula string adjust with each step of the loop.  Hoping you might please advise.  I'll edit my question above with revised code.

Comment: I saw the edit. Are you sure you want to loop over the various columns of data and just keep on updating *one* chart with all those?

Comment: Yes. I have a 100% stacked bar chart that shows the stacking plan of a property.  Y axis is floors of the building and X axis is square footages.  Values are square footages and these columns of data are labels describing which company is in which space.  $Z$4 is the beginning of a table that is adjacent to the table with the values that drive the chart.  A bit confusing to describe; I'd post a screenshot but am not level 10.  Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Fair enough. What is your beginning and ending columns? I take it `Z:Z` is your beginning. Where should the loop end?

Comment: Yes, Z:Z is the beginning.  I'm trying to account for up to 20 columns (i.e., companies per floor of the building), which would take me out to AS:AS.  But the chart will be reused with many buildings such that the loop needs to stop when there are no more series.  The currently coded loop does this much correctly.

Comment: I also observed that `finalrow` is supposed to be the *real* end of your StrFieldRange, isn't it? Not just row 159 of each column, yes? Do you want to use `finalrow` instead?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  In attempting to modify strfieldrange to reference other variables, I was getting an error that I needed an object and so couldn't incorporate this.

Comment: Kindly check the edit above. Test it in a copy of your workbook to avoid any unforeseen disaster. If it works the way you wanted it, I'll explain to you the code further.

Comment: Wow, thank you.  Very interesting.  No errors are being produced, but the labels that are being applied all appear to be based upon Z:Z (i.e., for each y value, all x labels are identical and correspond to the labels in Z:Z).  Perhaps the strfield component needs to be nested inside the datalabels portion of the loop?  Thanks again.

Comment: Just to avoid confusion, this is the logic of the above: we set first the initial "header" range, which is in row 4 (the start of data). Then we loop over each cell in the header range, resize it accordingly, and insert all the values there to the chart. We repeat this until the end of the header range, shifting one cell to the right each time automatically. Are you sure that after running the code, only `Z:Z`'s data appears to be repeatedly added?

Comment: Thank you for explaining.  Yes, 'Z:Z''s data is being repeated.  When I step through the macro and mouseover strfield, the pop-up tip tells me that the address is $Z$4:$Z$159 even after the series loop has progressed beyond the first loop.  The for each rngcell in rngheader loop is not stepping forward until _after_ all series have looped.

Comment: This is tricky.  I tried moving the rngcell loop inside the ser loop, but that results in every column of labels being successively written on top of series 1.  Seems like what's needed is a mechanism whereby the ser and the rngcell loops step forward together, instead of only one portion of the loop progressing while the other stays fixed.

Comment: Try this: the last line, change it from `Next` to `Next RngCell`. This shouldn't have an effect, but I want to see how it affects you.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't have the desired impact.  `Next Ser` acts first and causes the `Z:Z` labels to continue being applied to each successive series.  Then, when all of the series have looped, `Next RngCell` acts and moves the label column over to `AA:AA`.

Comment: This question appears to cover the same issue but I'm not sure how to properly apply it here.  [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534640/nested-for-loops-inside-loop-not-reacting]

Comment: If it's alright, kindly upload it to wikiupload or the like and post a link here. I'll try checking it myself. :)

Comment: Please let me know if this link works: [http://1drv.ms/Oq0m1v].  I posted the file to my Skydrive/Onedrive.  Should be a way to download the file even though it opens in an Excel web app.  This version is significantly reduced from the master, which is a corporate file that I'm not authorized to share.  Please let me know if you have questions once you open the file.  Tangentially, I'm also interested in building a macro to recolor each chart point in relation to the corresponding year in range `BW4:CQ159`.  One step at a time, though :) Thank you again very much for your willingness to help.

Comment: It appears that when you save the file down from the Excel web app, it strips out the VBA code (which I simply pasted in from your post above).

Comment: I've seen the file and I think it's safe to say that what you're doing is pretty close to impossible. Reason is, you can only have one series name at a time for the current set-up. You can test this manually by changing the name of one series to say, `Z:Z`. You'll notice all of them will change names to `Z:Z` as well. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: In my master file, it's actually a pivotchart (as opposed to a normal chart with 18 data series).  As a result, the pivotchart series are all locked into the pivottable that you see in AX4.  Each series ("0" through "17") is fixed.  I'm not sure if this changes your approach at all.  What is it in the set-up that prevents us from solving the issue with VBA?  Thanks again for taking a look.

Comment: Is there any way to adjust `Ser.DataLabels.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.InsertChartField msoChartFieldRange, StrField, 0` such that the actual string of `strfield` can sit inside the loop and use the series number to add 1 offset to the column each time the loop steps?  Since we can derive the count of series, the `ser` loop contains the information needed to adjust the offset.  What do you think?

Comment: Something like `"='Stacking RR'!" &` **my text:** range with row: 4 and column: "Z"+ser# to row: lastrow and column: "Z"+ser# `.Address`?

Comment: any idea how to change data label size??

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question properly.

However,

Try replacing `"=$A$1:$A$15"`

with `Range("A1:A15").Resize(10)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I'm in the early stages of learning and so left out some important clarifying info that Nanashi was able to glean in his reply.  Apologies for not being clearer but thanks again for taking a look.